# How to add +1 value to php

Tags: php, html, ajax, database

So I am making a pie chart with only PHP and Ajax. But I can't see how I must code further to make it work (see the first picture). So when someone clicks on button A B C or D, it must be seen (without page loading) that you have voted for one of them and also be seen in the chart. Actually that is it! The second image shows my database.

[image]

Before I forget to tell I DO NOT have a picture in my database to change.

[image]

I hope some of you can help me with this. Some of my code:

```
<p><h1>Breng jou stem uit</h1></p><br />
<form action = "<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>" method = "GET"> 
<button type="button" name="a">Partij A</button><br />
<button type="button" name="b">Partij B</button><br />
<button type="button" name="c">Partij C</button><br />
<button type="button" name="d">Partij D</button>
 </form>
<?php

// Connects to your Database

include('../../../connection.php');

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
echo $partijA = $row['partijA'];
$partijB = $row['partijB'];
$partijC = $row['partijC'];
$partijD = $row['partijD'];
if (isset($_GET['a'])) {
    echo $resultA = $partijA + 1;
} else {
    echo "1";
}

$resultB = $partijB + 1;
$resultC = $partijC + 1;
$resultD = $partijD + 1;
}

// Name of our cookie

$cookie = "Voted";

// A function to display our results - this refrences vote_pie.php which we     will also make

function pie()
{
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($data);
    $total  = $result[partijA] + $result[partijB] + $result[partijC] +      $result[partijD];
    $one    = round(360 * $result[partijA] / $total);
    $two    = round(360 * $result[partijB] / $total);
    $per1   = round($result[partijA] / $total * 100);
    $per2   = round($result[partijB] / $total * 100);
    $per3   = round($result[partijC] / $total * 100);
    $per4   = round($result[partijD] / $total * 100);
    echo "<img src=vote_pie.php?one=" . $one . "&two=" . $two . "><br/>";
    Echo "<font color=000000>Partij A</font> = $result[partijA] votes = $per1 <br /> 
         <font color=000000>Partij B</font> = $result[partijB] votes = $per2 <br />
         <font color=000000>Partij C</font> = $result[partijC] votes =  $per3 <br /> 
         <font color=000000>Partij D</font> = $result[partijD] votes = $per4 <br />";
}

// displays the poll results

pie();
?>
```

Comment: Forgot to say this was my base code... 

https://github.com/Goatella/PHPGraphicalPoll

Comment: `But I can't see how I must code further to make it work...` - What's not working on it? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow! To make your question more readable by your fellow coders. Please refrain from conversational writing, and focus instead on the core issue that you have. Images can be placed inline on your post, using the img tag. Please elaborate further on the issue that you face, it is not immediately obvious what problem you are having.

Comment: No none errors! The problem is I am a starter in PHP but I totally lost control on what I have to do to make this chart work. I know it is a simple thing to make for a more advanced programmer. 

All it has to do is add a value +1 when pressing A B C or D and it must be shown after votes= and in the chart.

Comment: Please ***stop using the `mysql` extension***, [read the red **warning** box](http://php.net/mysql_connect): The extension is deprecated, and will be removed in the future. If you're not seeing the `E_DEPRECATED` notice, set the error level to `E_ALL|E_STRICT` and turn `display_errors` on. For details, [check the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/migrating5.errorrep.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your code, but the one that causes the actual problems you're having is the fact that your function `pie` does not increment the values you fetched from the DB, that's done outside of the function, but the incremented values aren't used there:

```
function pie()
{
    //this query was already performed, pass the result resource to this function, don't re-run the query
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes") or die(mysql_error()); //google or die must die
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($data);//mysql is deprecated
    //array keys need to be quoted
    $total  = $result[partijA] + $result[partijB] + $result[partijC] +      $result[partijD];
    $one    = round(360 * $result[partijA] / $total);
    $two    = round(360 * $result[partijB] / $total);
    $per1   = round($result[partijA] / $total * 100);
    $per2   = round($result[partijB] / $total * 100);
    $per3   = round($result[partijC] / $total * 100);
    $per4   = round($result[partijD] / $total * 100);
    //functions return, they don't echo
    echo "<img src=vote_pie.php?one=" . $one . "&two=" . $two . "><br/>";
    Echo "<font color=000000>Partij A</font> = $result[partijA] votes = $per1 <br /> 
         <font color=000000>Partij B</font> = $result[partijB] votes = $per2 <br />
         <font color=000000>Partij C</font> = $result[partijC] votes =  $per3 <br /> 
         <font color=000000>Partij D</font> = $result[partijD] votes = $per4 <br />";
}
```

I've taken the liberty of adding some comments to point out several issues with the code.

Just remove the code that queries and increments outside of the `pie` function, and have your function do all of the work. Pass it the values it needs (ie `$_GET`, and have it ***return*** the result, instead of echoing it).
I'd rewrite the function to take arguments like so (not going into not using mysql at this point):

```
function getPie(array $params, $connection)
{
    //added limit 1, seeing as you're only processing the first result
    $result = mysql_query($connection, 'SELECT * from votes LIMIT 1');
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if (isset($params['a'])) {
        $row['partijA'] += 1;
    } else if (isset($params['b'])) {
        $row['partijB'] += 1;
    } //add more else's for all parties
    $percentages = [];//array
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        $percentages[$key] = round(($val/$total) * 100);
    }
    $total = array_sum($row);//total of all votes
    $markup = '<img src=vote_pie.php?one=' .
      $percentages['partijA']*360 . '&two=' . $percentages['partijB']*360 . '><br>';
    foreach ($percentages as $k => $perc) {
        $markup .= '<font color=000000>Partij ' . str_replace('partij', $k) . '</font> = '.
            $row[$key] . ' votes = ' . $perc . '<br>';
    }
    return $markup;
}
```

Then call this function like so:

```
if ($_GET) {//if a get form was submitted
    echo getPie($_GET, $db);//where $db holds the mysql resource
}
```

That's just a quick-fix, though... there's still a long way to go...

## What I changed:

A quick canter through the actual changes I've made:

- Passing arguments to the function: the function now takes 2 arguments, an array (the `$_GET` values in this case), and the db connection to use.
- Loops instead of repetition: instead of repeating `round($resutl['key']/total*100)`, I've used a loop, so I only have to write this statement once, and have it applied to all values
- use an array for the percentages: Instead of assigning the percentage for each party to a new variable, I've opted to use an array instead. This keeps data that belongs together, well... together
- Loops to create markup: Though I find stringing together markup bad practice, I've noticed most of the HTML is actually identical, so instead of hard-coding everything, I simply iterate over either the `$row` or `$percentages` array (they both have the same keys), and fill in the specific values. This also means that I can safely add a party without having to change the code that creates markup